# How to define some kind of inheritance between structs in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, inheritance, struct

Talking about structs, is it possible to just copy a `struct`'s fields to another `struct` without explicitly calling the type field name?

Let me show you an example:

```
struct StructA
{
   char Name[20];
   int Age;
};

struct StructB
{
   StructA FieldStructA;

   int SomeOtherDeclarations;
   // ...
};
```

So, I could access the `StructA` fields on `StructB` doing this:

```
StructB strB;
strB.FieldStructA.Name[0] = 0;
```

What I want to do is access the `StructA` fields through `StructB` without accessing the data field on StructB. Something like inheritance between classes. Like this:

```
StructB strB;
strB.Name[0] = 0;
```

I want to inherit `StructA` fields on `StructB`. I know that I could do that with classes, but I have to use struct for some reasons (interop, specific use of stack and so on).

Thanks for your time!

Comment: In C++ classes and structs are the *same* thing except for the default visibility of fields. Everything you can do with a class, you can also do with a struct.

Comment: If you settle on  C++ there *is* inheritance for structs, just like for classes. `struct B : A { };` works perfectly well.

Comment: Your answer is in the question title. If you are talking about C++. You should pick one of the two languages, really.

Comment: @Sylence: Another difference is that the inheritance of structs is `public` by default (it's `private` for classes).

Comment: How about writing C++ instead of C, i.e., `std::string name;`.  Even in C I would probably use a dynamically allocated chunk of memory instead of a fixed size array.  How would you possibly account for Mr. Frued Von Bissmark III?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: That's what Sylence meant, I'm reasonably sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using gcc, try making it an anonymous member:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html

```
struct StructA
{
  char Name[20];
  int Age;
};

struct StructB
{
   struct StructA;

   int SomeOtherDeclarations;
   // ...
};
```

Comment: There is no need for GCC. C11 officially has that feature. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in C++ using inheritance:

```
struct StructB: public StructA
{
   int SomeOtherDeclarations;
   // ...
};
```

Given that, you can then do

```
StructB strB;
strB.Name[0] = 0;
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the default inheritance for structs is `public` already - so you could omit that if you like.

Comment: I'd prefer always being explicit about it. It'll just end up confusing people otherwise.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for C++ and mine is the best answer for C.  Too bad the OP asked two questions in one.

Comment: The problem of doing this is that with inheritance I can only set the base struct fields starting at offset 0. What if I have to put those fields at offset 200h for example? Thanks btw for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

In plain C, you have 2 choices as I see it:

1 - define those fields with a macro. Then you can use them in two structs

```
#define PERSON_FIELDS \
char Name[20]; \
int Age; \

struct StructA
{
STRUCT_A_FIELDS
};

struct StructB
{
   STRUCT_A_FIELDS

   int thing;
   // ...
};
```

and you can then use

```
StructB strB;
strB.Name[0] = 0;


StructA strA;
strA.Name[0] = 0;
```

In this case, `StructA` and `StructB` have no connection to each other. But you have the same fields. This gives you at least a bit of modularisation. Macros like this are commonly used to achieve/fake things that newer languages give you (such as inheritance or genericity).

2 - **Alternatively** you could keep your above code but use accessor functions to get the values:

```
struct StructA
{
   char Name[20];
   int Age;
};

struct StructB
{
   StructA FieldStructA;

   int thing;
   // ...
};


int StructB_Thing(struct Struct *obj)
{
    return obj->thing;
}

int StructB_Age(struct Struct *obj)
{
    return obj->FieldStructA.Age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, inheritance is used for interface re-use, not implementation reuse. You can easily get the latter C, but the former requires being aware of a little trick:

```
struct StructA
{
   char Name[20];
   int Age;
};

struct StructB
{
   StructA FieldStructA;

   int SomeOtherDeclarations;
   // ...
};
```

The trick is to understand that you can do

```
void setAge( struct StructA *s, int age ) {
    s->Age = age;
}

struct StructB b;
setAge( (struct StructA *)&b, 33 );
/* b.FieldStructA.Age is now 33 */
```

Note how you don't have to mention `FieldStructA` anywhere here: the code works because the 'base' fields are actually the first members of the 'derived' struct. So a value of type `struct StructB *` can be used in places where you access fields via a `struct StructA *`. This is the interface reuse: the same set of functions used for accessing `StructA` can be used for accessing the same fields in a `StructB`.